# Could not open jmx file while running JMeter command line

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, filenotfoundexception, jmeter-5.0

I have run a thread group in JMeter in GUI mode it is working and getting results, but while running same ThreadGroup.jmx file through terminal(Non GUI] mode,I am getting an error `Couldn't load .jmx file`.

Can anybody suggest me how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please share the command you are using to run the test, with the relative paths of the file.

Comment: Is "Thraed" in the title a typo?

Comment: I have used below command: sh jmeter -n -t /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/examples/SampleThreadGroup.jmx -l /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/Result.csv

Answer (score 3):

In linux using files is **case sensitive**, so use exact letters(as sampleThreadGroup.jmx)

Also make sure the file is saved in the correct folder

And check your user have permission to execute it (try `chmod 777` for jmx file)